# Output register in Shor's algorithm

Tags: factoring, cryptography, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

In Shor's [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9508027.pdf) he creates two registers, sets the first to uniform superposition for each possible number $a \text{(mod $q$)}$, and then computes $x^a \text{(mod $n$)}$ into the second register. He then goes on to apply the Fourier Transform to the first register and subsequently measures it. It seems to me that the value of the second register is used at no point. In fact he writes that "it would be sufficient to observe solely the value [...] in the first register, [...]."

Thus my question, what is the second, "output" register used for at all? I've read that in later versions, one first reads the second register to collapse the first into a non-uniform superposition corresponding to the measurement, and then applies QFT. But in Shor's paper he does not do this. What is the point of the second register in the original paper?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original paper, Shor uses the second register to compute $x^a (\mod n)$ while $a$ is kept in the first register. He mentions this allows reversibility of the modular exponentiation operation done on the second register. In the paper you provided in the link it is there in the paragraph preceding Eqn $(5.2)$.

> [image: Snippet from Shor's paper]

Comment: I see, I didn't understand what he meant by "this can be done reversibly". To my shame I have to admit I sort of skipped chapter 3 at first. Still, it is not clear to me where this reversibility is used?

Comment: He talks about that in context setting about Benioff's result.

*The first person to look at the interaction between computation and quantum mechanics appears to have been Benioff [1980, 1982a, 1982b]. Although he did not ask whether quantum mechanics conferred extra power to computation, he showed that reversible unitary evolution was sufficient to realize the computational power of a Turing machine, thus showing that quantum mechanics is at least as powerful computationally as a classical computer. This work was fundamental in making later investigation of quantum computers possible*

Comment: That quote doesn't really illuminate where the reversibility is used though, does it?

Comment: See section 3.  *Reversible logic and modular exponentiation*

Comment: In section 3 he explains how reversible exponentiation is done, and why quantum computers have to use reversible computation. At no point did I see a reason for actually doing the exponentiation later on... (he does say *that* it is necessary on p. 10, just not why..) I feel like I missed an important point somewhere..

Comment: In section 3., in the first few paragraphs he is talking about the Toffoli and Fredkin gates and how they are universal quantum gates and he connects how they enable reversible quantum computation. He also shows linkages with how reversibility of computation is necessary for the quantum computer to perform deterministic computation. Therefore, the second register is required to ensure determinism of the computation.

Comment: I think I got it, though I'll have to spend a little more time on the details. Thanks!